# JS: корректна ли проверка на IE?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, браузер

Определяю IE с помощью вот такой конструкции:

```
 if (/MSIE 9/i.test(navigator.userAgent) || /MSIE
 10/i.test(navigator.userAgent) || /rv:11.0/i.test(navigator.userAgent)
 || /Edge\/\d./i.test(navigator.userAgent))
```

В `IE-11` работает. Будет ли работать в `9, 10 и Edge`?

И, может быть, есть какая-то более корректная, универсальная конструкция?